# MySQL Stored Procedure - Nested loop at fault?

Tags: mysql, datetime, stored-procedures, cursor

I have a medium sized stored procedure going on here below. My problem is that it doesn't do anything and I have no idea why.

1.) First of all, the code:

```
    DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS deleteabundant_fixshared_shiftResources;
    DELIMITER //
    CREATE PROCEDURE deleteabundant_fixshared_shiftResources ()
    BEGIN
      DECLARE finish_flag BOOLEAN DEFAULT FALSE;
      DECLARE id INT(11);
      DECLARE startTime DATETIME;
      DECLARE endTime DATETIME;
      DECLARE shid INT(11);
      DECLARE resid INT(11);

      DECLARE id_inner INT(11);
      DECLARE startTime_inner DATETIME;
      DECLARE endTime_inner DATETIME;
      DECLARE shid_inner INT(11);
      DECLARE resid_inner INT(11);
      DECLARE cr130 CURSOR FOR SELECT shift_resource_id, start_date, end_date, shift_id, resource_id FROM temp_shift_resource;
      DECLARE cr131 CURSOR FOR SELECT shift_resource_id, start_date, end_date, shift_id, resource_id FROM temp_shift_resource;
        DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER  FOR NOT FOUND SET finish_flag = TRUE; 

    START TRANSACTION;  



    OPEN cr130;
    OPEN cr131;
        OUTERLOOP: LOOP
        FETCH cr130 into id, startTime, endTime, shid, resid;
        IF finish_flag THEN LEAVE OUTERLOOP; END IF;
            INNERLOOP: LOOP
            FETCH cr131 INTO id_inner, startTime_inner, endTime_inner, shid_inner, resid_inner;
        IF finish_flag THEN LEAVE INNERLOOP; END IF;
        IF (id!=id_inner) THEN
        IF (resid=resid_inner AND shid_inner!=9) THEN

     -- logic to determine if the dates are wrong:
            IF (startTime<=startTime_inner AND endTime>=endTime_inner) THEN
                INSERT INTO repairchange ( shift_resource_id, changetype, shift_id, resource_id, start_date, end_date ) 
                                  VALUES ( id_inner, "FD", shid_inner, resid_inner, startTime_inner, endTime_inner );
                DELETE FROM temp_shift_resource WHERE shift_resource_id = id_inner;
            ELSEIF (endTime>=endTime_inner AND startTime<=endTime_inner) THEN
                INSERT INTO repairchange ( shift_resource_id, changetype, shift_id, resource_id, start_date, end_date ) 
                                  VALUES ( id_inner, "FU", shid_inner, resid_inner, startTime_inner, endTime_inner );
                UPDATE temp_shift_resource set endTime_inner=(startTime - INTERVAL 1 DAY) where shift_resource_id = id_inner;
            ELSEIF (startTime<=startTime_inner AND endTime>=startTime_inner) THEN
                INSERT INTO repairchange ( shift_resource_id, changetype, shift_id, resource_id, start_date, end_date ) 
                                  VALUES ( id_inner, "FU", shid_inner, resid_inner, startTime_inner, endTime_inner );
                UPDATE temp_shift_resource set startTime_inner=(endTime + INTERVAL 1 DAY) where shift_resource_id = id_inner;
            END IF;
    END IF;     
    END IF;
            END LOOP INNERLOOP;
    SET finish_flag = FALSE;
      END LOOP OUTERLOOP;
      CLOSE cr130;
      CLOSE cr131;



    COMMIT;

    END //
    DELIMITER ;

    call deleteabundant_fixshared_shiftResources();
```

2.) Description of what I want to do:

Basically, I have a table full of workshifts. Due to code bugs, some of these shifts have a wrong date assigned to them, and I have to fix the database.

- I have to run through the whole table, and compare the rows that are assigned to the same **resource_id**, which represents a person. So if a person has two shifts that look like (2016-05-10 to 2016-05-20) and (2016-05-15 to 2016-05-23) for example, I have to fix it so that one of them will be trimmed to (2016-05-10 to 2016-05-14) and (2016-05-15 to 2016-05-23).
- A shift that is a nightshift, marked as **shift_id**=9, must not be modified at all.
- I insert rows into the repairchange table if a change or a deletion has been made

3.) The procedure runs, but does nothing. I have examples in the database for wrong rows, one example is the one I wrote above. I suspect it is the nested loop, because I want to loop and fetch through the same table, but I haven't found anything on that.
I got the message

0 row(s) affected, 1 warning(s): 1329 No data - zero rows fetched, selected, or processed

but I have seen this before and my stored procedures have worked even though they output this warning.

Any ideas or tips are welcome. Thank you for your time!

Comment: Little update: I added a line "select * from temp_shift_resource;" in the LOOPINNER, it ran quite some times, so it seems the loops are working, but the fetching might not?

Comment: Little update 2: Added DATE(startTime) around so only dates would be compared, shouldnt bother the result though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, after quite some debugging:

I opened the cursors before both of the loops. This meant that after the first walk-through of the inner loop, the cursor was standing at +1 of the LAST row of the table, and when the new outer loop iteration started the second inner loop iteration, the cursor was still at the end position.

Thus it did not run. I replaced the inner-cursor opening and closing into the outer loop, and now it works properly.